# How can I implement " for (int i=0; i<str.size; i= i*5) " in python using for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

**Can I use range() here, or is there any other way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `while` for this:

```
i = 0 // maybe 1 would be better?
while i < someSize:
    doSomething()
    i *= 5
```

Just be aware that this is an infinite loop (unless `someSize` is zero, of course) if, as you did in your title, you start at zero. It doesn't matter *how* many time you multiply zero by five, you'll always end up with zero.

---

As an aside, there's nothing to stop you creating your *own* iterator, even one that calls a function to decide the next value and whether the iterator should stop.

The following code provides such a beast, one where you specify the initial value and a pair of functions to update and check the values (implemented as lambdas in the test code):

```
# Iterator which uses a start value, function for calculating next value,
# and function for determining whether to continue, similar to standard
# C/C++ for loop (not C++ range-for, Python already does that).

class FuncIter(object):
    def __init__(self, startVal, continueProc, changeProc):
        # Store all relevant stuff.

        self.currVal = startVal
        self.continueProc = continueProc
        self.changeProc = changeProc

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # If allowed to continue, return current and prepare next.

        if self.continueProc(self.currVal):
            retVal = self.currVal
            self.currVal = self.changeProc(self.currVal)
            return retVal

        # We're done, stop iterator.

        raise StopIteration()

print([item for item in FuncIter(1, lambda x: x <= 200, lambda x: x * 4 - 1)])
```

The expression:

```
FuncIter(1, lambda x: x <= 200, lambda x: x * 4 - 1)
```

generates the values that you would get with the equivalent C/C++ `for` statement:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 200; i = i * 4 - 1)
```

as shown by the output:

```
[1, 3, 11, 43, 171]
```

Comment: Terminology nitpick, that isn't a generator, that's an iterator

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, good point, have adjusted answer to use the correct terminology.